# How can I migrate attachments from SharePoint ListItems into a SQL Server FILESTREAM column using SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint list containing news articles that I want to migrate out of SharePoint and into my own SQL Server database table named `NewsArticle`.  The list includes items with attachments that will need to go into an `NewsArticleAttachment` table that uses `FILESTREAM`.

Here is my SharePoint list:

- Home - News

  - ID
  - Title
  - Description
  - Created

Here are my SQL Server database tables:

- `NewsArticle`

  - `Id`
  - `Title`
  - `Description`
  - `Created`
- `NewsArticleAttachment`

  - `Id`
  - `NewsArticleFK`
  - `Name`
  - `UniqueID` (uniqueidentifier, rowguidcol)
  - `File` (varbinary(max), FILESTREAM)

How can I accomplish this using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Data Flow Task?

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites

- Download the SharePoint List Source adapter from [CodePlex](https://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/) before it goes away.  I haven't found a new location where they are going to host it.

For the Data Flow

1. Add a "SharePoint List Source" pointing to your "Home - News" list.
2. Add a "Conditional Split" that will check if there are any attachments.
3. Add a "Lookup" to pull the matching `Id` column from the `NewsArticle` table based on the natural key of the SharePoint list.  We will need this for the `NewsArticleFK` column.  In this case we will use the `Title` column of the SharePoint list to match up with the `Title` column of the SQL table.
4. Create the following variables

   - SharePoint_Url: "http://mysharepoint.mydomain.com"
   - SharePoint_Account_Domain: "mydomain.com"
   - SharePoint_Account_Username: "myusername"
   - SharePoint_Account_Password: "mypassword"
   - SharePoint_List_Guid: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
   - SharePoint_List_ServiceUrl: "http://mysharepoint.mydomain.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
5. Add a "Script Component" to actually pull down the attachments from SharePoint.

   1. On the "Script" section add the variables from step 4 to the list of "ReadOnlyVariables".
   2. On the "Input Columns" tab select both the `ID` column from the SharePoint list and the `Id` column from the `NewsArticle` table.
   3. On the "Inputs and Outputs" tab add a new Output called "Attachments".  We need to create a new Output because we may have news articles with multiple attachments and this will allow us to create multiple output rows from a single input row.  Here are the columns needed:

      1. UniqueID (DT_GUID)
      2. AttachmentFile (DT_IMAGE)
      3. FileName (DT_WSTR)
      4. NewsArticleId (DT_I4)
   4. Go back to the "Script" tab and click the "Edit Script..." button.  See the code below for details.

```
//This is referring to a Service Reference that will need to be created
using SC_be93317446654a518077a828ff747bd1.SharePointListsService;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Xml;
```

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
  BasicHttpBinding listsSoapBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
  listsSoapBinding.Name = "ListsSoap";
  listsSoapBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
  listsSoapBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
    HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

  EndpointAddress listsSoapAddress = 
    new EndpointAddress(Variables.SharePointListServiceUrl); 

  ListsSoapClient listsSoapClient = 
    new ListsSoapClient(listsSoapBinding, listsSoapAddress);

  XmlElement attachmentCollection = listsSoapClient.GetAttachmentCollection(
    Variables.SharePointListGuid, Row.ID.ToString());

  foreach(XmlNode node in attachmentCollection.ChildNodes)
  {
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
      AttachmentsBuffer.AddRow();

      CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
      credentialCache.Add(
          new Uri(Variables.SharePointUrl),
          "NTLM",
          new NetworkCredential(
            Variables.SharePointAccountUsername, 
            Variables.SharePointAccountPassword, 
            Variables.SharePointAccountDomain));
      client.Credentials = credentialCache;

      string attachmentUrl = node.InnerText;

      byte[] data = client.DownloadData(attachmentUrl);

      AttachmentsBuffer.AttachmentFile.AddBlobData(data);
      AttachmentsBuffer.FileName = Path.GetFileName(node.InnerText);
      AttachmentsBuffer.NewsArticleId = Row.NewsArticleId;
      AttachmentsBuffer.UniqueID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
  }
}
```

Here are things to note about the code:

- Create a Service Reference to the SharePoint Lists.asmx.  The url should be the same as the `SharePoint_List_ServiceUrl` variable.
- Create the service bindings using code because the SSIS package will not actually be able to load from the app.config that is created.
- Use an instance of the service reference to call the `GetAttachmentCollection` to actually pull the attachment urls from SharePoint.
- Use a `WebClient` to download the attachments from their urls.
- Use the `AddBlobData` method on your `AttachmentFile` column to actually set the attachment data in your new column.